# xpath where clause returning 0 nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

My where clause in this xpath expression is not working and always returning 0. I cannot figure out what is wrong.  The code is here. The value of the currentRelationship variable is 'testentity_relname.';

```
var entity = doc.SelectNodes(string.Format("//Settings/Entity[RelationshipName={0}]", currentRelationship)).Cast<XmlNode>().ToList();
```

And the XML document looks like this;

```
<Settings>
  <AccessRightTypes>
    <AccessRightType>WriteAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>ShareAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>ReadAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>NoneAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>DeleteAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>CreateAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>AssignAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>AppendToAccess</AccessRightType>
    <AccessRightType>AppendAccess</AccessRightType>
  </AccessRightTypes>
  <Entity>
    <RelationshipName>testentity_relname.</RelationshipName>
    <AccessRight>ReadAccess</AccessRight>
    <AccessRight>WriteAccess</AccessRight>
  </Entity>
</Settings>
```

If i use the xpath expression of just "//Settings/Entity" I do get the single Entity node back.  But again, the where clause does not work.  And info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do be aware of the risk of injection attacks if you construct expressions like this using string concatenation; also the expression could be syntactically invalid if it contains quotation marks. It's better if possible to use a variable reference in the XPath expression. As far as I know the SelectNodes() method doesn't allow variable references in the XPath expression but there are other APIs that do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing single quotes around the argument in the xpath format string.

```
var entity = doc.SelectNodes(string.Format("//Settings/Entity[RelationshipName='{0}']", currentRelationship)).Cast<XmlNode>().ToList();
```